# Intellij gradle directory not marked after reload gradle

Tags: spring, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

If you add or remove libraries from the build.gradle.kts file in IntelliJ and then refresh(reload) the gradle, the mark in the src/main/kotlin subdirectory will continue to be disabled.

Therefore, I need to set the kotlin folder to Mark Directory as Sources Root every time I reload Gradle.

In Projects Structure, when I mark directly in Modules > Sources, the following warning message appears.
"Module 'project' is imported from Gradle. Any changes made in its configuration might be lost after reimporting"

What should I modify?

[image]
[image]

root build.gradle.kts

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.9" apply false
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.15.RELEASE" apply false
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.6.21"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.6.21"
}

allprojects {
    apply(plugin = "java") 

    group = "com.jh"
    version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
    java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    java.targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply(plugin = "org.springframework.boot")
    apply(plugin = "io.spring.dependency-management")

    dependencies {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
        testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    }

    tasks.register("prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

}
```

Comment: Is it possible to share project example?

Comment: There is nothing special about the project structure, and I changed the package name in the middle of the spring boot multi-module, but the setting seems to have been a little twisted since then.

Comment: Could you please attach screenshots demonstrating the issue? It seems to be working as expected on my side.

Comment: @y.bedrov yes, I attached the image.
Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Is it possible to share sample project example? It works fine with test project and provided build.gradle.kts on my side.